# keynames starting with underscore in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, nosql

Is there anyway to have names prefixed with underscore in couchDB. I keep getting errors if I have key names starting with underscore.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In CouchDB documents, keys are not allowed to have `_` as a prefix, as those are reserved for use by CouchDB itself. (examples include: `_id`, `_rev`, `_deleted`, `_attachments`, etc)

A lot of other characters are acceptable here, such as `$`, which I hear most commonly. However, I would argue that such prefixes are unnecessary, but it's entirely up to your application needs.